# How to find the mean of a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and trying to write some code so that the user enters something. If it's an integer it's sorted into the Numbers list, if it's a string it goes into the String list.

I want to be able to find the mean of all the numbers that are in the list and print out the result.
And in the String section I want to be able to print out everything within the string and its length.
User types 'save' to exit and if input is valid that's caught.

```
Numbers = []
String = []

while(True):
    user_input = input("What's your input? ")
    if user_input == "save":
        break
    elif user_input.isdigit():
        Numbers.append(user_input)
        for i in range(len(Numbers)):
            Numbers[i] = int(Numbers[i])
            print(sum(Numbers)/len(Numbers)
    elif isinstance(user_input, str):
        String.append(user_input)
        print(String)
        print (len(String)-1)
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        break
```

Comment: On the line `print(sum(Numbers)/len(Length)`, you appear to be missing a close bracket (`)`). Is this a typo when copying to the site?

Comment: you don't need to convert all numbers to integers each time! And `len(Length)` must also by a typo. Should be `len(Numbers)` and be computed out of the loop. BTW won't work for negative numbers because of `isdigit()` method.

Comment: Updated the typo thank you, but still didn't fix issues, and I don't want to account for negatives just positives

Comment: What in your posted code, or even the description of the problem, says anything out eliminating negatives?

Answer (score 2):

```
#use isalpha to check enterted input is string or not
#isalpha returns a boolean value

Numbers = []
String = []

while(True):
    user_input = input("input : ")
    if user_input == "save":
        break
    elif user_input.isdigit():
        Numbers.append(int(user_input))
        print(sum(Numbers)/len(Numbers))
    elif user_input.isalpha():
        String.append(user_input)
        print(String)
        print (len(String))
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

There is good thing called [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean):

```
from statistics import mean
mean(your_list)
```

Comment: I've been asked to do this without importing anything and just to do it through coding.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Length`, which has not been defined.  I think what you wanted was

```
print(sum(Numbers)/len(Numbers))
```

and you probably don't want it inside the loop, but just after it (although that might be another typo).

Comment: Apologies, updated the code to have the right variable, was a mistake in typing.

Answer (score 0):

I found other more convenient way to produce the mean: Use statistics model and output the mean.

```
#import useful packages
import statistics

#Create an empty list
user_list = []

#get user request
user_input = input("Welcome to the average game. The computer is clever enough to get the average of the list of numbers you give. Please press enter to have a try.")

#game start
while True:
    #user will input their number into a the empty list
    user_number = input("Type the number you want to input or type 'a' to get the average and quit the game:")

#help the user to get an average number
if user_number == 'a':
    num_average = statistics.mean(user_list)
    print("The mean is: {}.".format(num_average))
    break #Game break
else:
    user_list.append(int(user_number))
    print(user_list)
```